# Map View cannot add more than 2 annotations (pins)

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a map view in my app, and every time I add a third annotation (pin) it shows the ARGV running error in the mainDelegate.m file?  Code below:

```
  [super viewDidLoad];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
    region.center.latitude = 53.321927;
    region.center.longitude = -6.250504;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    MapPin *sandford = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    sandford.title = @"Sandford Park";
    sandford.subtitle = @"Ranelagh";
    sandford.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:sandford];

    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
    region2.center.latitude = 53.324089;
    region2.center.longitude = -6.252080;
    region2.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region2.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    [mapview setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

    MapPin *Cinnamon = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    Cinnamon.title = @"Cinnamon";
    Cinnamon.subtitle = @"Ranelagh";
    Cinnamon.coordinate = region2.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:Cinnamon];

    MKCoordinateRegion region3 = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
    region3.center.latitude = 53.325010;
    region3.center.longitude = -6254461;
    region3.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region3.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    [mapview setRegion:region3 animated:YES];

    MapPin *Gommels = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    Gommels.title = @"Gommels";
    Gommels.subtitle = @"Ranelagh";
    Gommels.coordinate = region3.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:Gommels];
```

The first two work fine but the third stops the simulator every time

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: Would you explain what you're trying to do? Your code makes no sense - you are calling `mapView setRegion` three times in succession, which is pointless since it can only show one region.

Comment: it doesn't say, just the second that I click on the map icon it switches from the simulator to a page of code that says:    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,   NSStringFromClass([RecipeAppDelegate class]));

Comment: That's a red herring. The console must say _something_, at least.

Comment: You say "the second you click on the map icon". But the code you are showing has nothing to do with clicking on anything; it's from `viewDidLoad`. You need to figure out and show the _relevant_ code. We can't see you project from here; you have to do the work before you ask the question.

Comment: I am trying to put in a third map pin onto my mapview, the first two worked when i tried them on the simulator, but the when i put in the reference for the third map pin the map didnt respond on the app and brought me to the code i showed abover

Comment: also, the code it is from the ViewDidLoad, read the code

Comment: "didnt respond on the app and brought me to the code i showed above". What does brought me to the code mean?

Comment: It just exited the simulator and went back onto a page in xcode

Comment: The answer by @MartinH is correct (you can Accept it).  But as a side note, you don't need to create a region and call setRegion just to define a coordinate for each annotation.  To set an annotation's coordinate, you can just do `sandford.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.321927, -6.250504);`, etc.  It is not necessary to call setRegion to _add_ an annotation -- it just positions the map so the last call will be where the map is positioned.

Answer (score 2):

-6254461 seems pretty big for a longitude value. I presume it should be -6.254461.

You blew the map's mind, it couldn't cope with that value.

Comment: Wow, i cannot believe I didn't see that...thank you so much you just saved me from hours of head banging! Thanks :)